# How to insert booleans into a bitfield in C89

Tags: c, boolean, bit-fields, c89

As far as I understand, in C89 all boolean expressions are of type integer. This also means that function parameters that represent bool usually get represented by an `int` parameter.

Now my question is how I can most ideally take such an `int` and put it into a bitfield so that it only occupies one bit (let's ignore padding for now).

The first thing here is which type to use. Using `int` or any other unsigned type doesn't work, because when there is only one bit, only `-1` and `0` can be represented (at least with two's complement).

While `-1` technically evaluates as `true`, this is not ideal because actually assigning it without undefined behavior can be quite tricky from what I understand.

So an unsigned type should be chosen for the bitfield:

```
typedef struct bitfield_with_boolean {
    unsigned int boolean : 1;
} bitfield_with_boolean;
```

The next question is then how to assign that bitfield. Just taking an `int` or similar won't work because the downcast truncates the value so if the lowest bit wasn't set, a value that would previously evaluate to `true` would now suddenly evaluate to `false`.

As far as I understand, the boolean operators are guaranteed to always return either `0` or `1`. So my idea to solve this problem would be something like this:

```
#define to_boolean(expression) (!!(expression))
```

So in order to assign the value I would do:

```
bitfield_with_boolean to_bitfield(int boolean) {
    bitfield_with_boolean bitfield = {to_boolean(boolean)};

    return bitfield;
}
```

Is that correct, and or is there a better way?

**NOTE:**

I know the problem is completely solved starting with C99 because casting to `_Bool` is guaranteed to always result in either a `0` or a `1`. Where `0` is only the result if the input had a value of `0`.

Comment: yeah `(!!(expression))` is a classic to boolean conversion.

Comment: Sidenote: don't use outdated non-standard C. Yas you wrote, C99 provided a boolean type (although logical expressions still generate an `int` result for compatibility reasons). If you rtoolchain does not support C11 (or at least C99), get a modern compiler. Re. bitfields in general: don't use them. Use bit-ops instead. Almost everything about bitfields is implementation-specific, including whether an `int` bitfield is signed or unsigned. They are broken by design.

Comment: @Olaf ... If I could, I wouldn't use C at all, I would use Rust. Or maybe C++17 and not C89. It's just that in the real world there sometimes are constraints that are far from ideal.

Comment: C11 is fine, C99 acceptable (although I wish they had cut off legacies more  consequently). There is also no use in shooting sparrows with nukes. For far by most projects there is a reasonable way to use at least C99, which is mostly identical with the non-optional parts of C11. THe reason C90 is still used is plain ignorance for new developments by "devs" not wanting to learn something new. Unfortunately quite some of them never learned the pitfalls systematically, thus their code invokes UB. Which is also the reason they complain modern compilers "break" their code (opposite is true).

Comment: @Olaf Good thing that MSVC didn't support even C99 up until recently. And there are some embedded toolchains stuck on C89.

Comment: @Olaf: And I know the pitfalls and am terrified and do my best to throw tools on it to avoid them. But the same is true for newer C standards.

Comment: @FSMaxB: MCVC never supported C99 and still does not afaik. Unless they changed their attitude towards C features without C++ counterpart like VLAs. And - with all due respect - if you are "terrified" about the C pitfalls, you might not have understood the few simple fundamental concepts of C. Such problems often arise if people don't get the whole picture, but e.g. learn the language from obscure online tutorials or youtube-videos (not saying you did). Far by most computer systems thgese days (and in the forseeable future) are programmed in C for good reasons.

Comment: The problem is a lot of university tutors don't know C well either and are not able to give their students a good grasp on the language. Plus the language is taought in intro courses only, but not really practiced.

Comment: @Olaf MSVC supports C99 since VS 2015 or so. And the reason I'm terrified is that even though I know what I'm doing, even though I use Valgrind, AddressSanitizer, UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer, Clang Tidy, cppcheck, Clang static Analyzer, Coverity and AFL for fuzzing on Big and Little Endian Systems, still some security critical Bugs slip through.

Comment: Once more: please provide proof they support VLAs and FAMs! The info I have is they claim to support C11, but only the mandatory features (which happened to exclude the aforementioned features which were mandatory in C99). Making language-features optional is contrary to the policy of bmaintaining backwards compatibility, btw. Honi soit qui mal y pense and the like. Btw: MSVC is one of the worst C compilers anyway. Get a modern one. But your reply is typical for a PC-only person. x86, ARM Cortex-A, PPC, even MIPS are a minority of computers. And there is no bug-free program, no matter the lang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct. However, I wouldn't hide it behind a macro, and I wouldn't name a macro using `all_lowercase` letters.

`!!var` is sufficiently idiomatic that I'd say it's fine in code.

Alternatives include `var != 0` and, of course, `var ? 1 : 0`.

Comment: Thanks, that increases my confidence XD

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `if (foo)` is equivalent to `if (foo != 0)`. What do you mean by "isn't that good"?

Comment: `0` is a null pointer constant. The code is semantically correct and equivalent to the `!!` version.

Comment: I like to have a macro because it allows me to document what I'm doing for readers of my code that aren't too familiar with how C works. And I can add a comment as to why right next to the macro.

Comment: @FSMaxB In that case I'd use the standard `ALL_UPPERCASE` convention for macros, e.g. `#define TO_BOOL(X) (!!(X))`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre C99, 6.3.2.3/3: "*An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
`void *`, is called a null pointer constant.*"